# How to create a content type to embed video in drupal 6?

Tags: files, nodes

I want to create content type to embed videos.

When admin want to post an article which will have a video content then he will just provide the video link in the field and then automatically video will be get embedded into that article.

Currently I have created a new content type but there is no field type to embed video link.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Embedded Media Field](https://drupal.org/project/emfield) module. After enabling just paste the URL of the video, it will render the video on the page. It supports almost all the videos like youtube, vimeo, etc..

> This extensible module will create fields for content types that can
>   be used to display video, image, and audio files from various third
>   party providers. When entering the content, the user will simply paste
>   the URL or embed code from the third party, and the module will
>   automatically determine which content provider is being used. When
>   displaying the content, the proper embedding format will be used.